# N does not name a type

Tags: c++, class, pointers

```
// q.h file
#ifndef __Q_H__
#define __Q_H__


using namespace std;
#include "n.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>


class Q
{
  public:
   Q();


  private:
   N* beginning; //error N does not name a type
   N* end;       //error N does not name a type
   int count;

};

#endif // end of file




// q.cpp file 
#include "q.h"
#include "n.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<string>

Q::Q()
{

beginning = NULL;
end = NULL;

}


// n.h file
#ifndef _N_H__
#define _N_H__
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>

#include "q.h"


class N
{
  public:

  N(int);
  // next is a pointer object of type N
  N* next;
  // memeber for Node class
  int value;
};
#endif

// n.cpp file 
#include<string>
#include "q.h"
#include "n.h"



N::N(int v)
{
    value = v;

}
```

I get an error at the following lines below. I tried changing user namespace std; to the first line of each file but that still does not work. I've also tried changing the order of q.h and n.h in which they are presented but still nothing.

N* beginning;
 N* end;

Also I know one great solution is by using "forward declare" but this is part of a test file that i given to me by someone so I cannot do a forward declaration of a class.

So if anyone can please just take a look and see how I can fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't get any error compiling with g++. That being said you have lots of unnecessary includes. You don't need `n.h` in `q.cpp`, `q.h` in `n.h` and `q.h` in `n.cpp`

Comment: Besides the circular include, you use reserved identifiers for your header guards. They must not start with double underscore or underscore and an uppercase character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a circular reference (`q.h` includes `n.h` and `n.h` includes `q.h`). This error occurs because the compiler is including (maybe because the main program) `q.h` before than `n.h`. Thus, `q.h` need to include an empty class declaration as follows to `Q` knows about `N`.

```
...
#include <string>

class N;

class Q
{
...
```

If you can't edit those files, you still can add the empty class declaration anywhere before the "Q" class declaration (e.g. before including `q.h` in your main program). However, the class `N` don't need anything from `Q`, so you don't need to include `q.h` in `n.h`.

Comment: i wrote on there that i cannot add an empty class because its a test file given to me. but i will try by editing the circular references.

Comment: You can add the empty class declaration anywhere before the "Q" class declaration, even in your main program. I suppose you can edit your main program.

Answer (score 2):

Since `#include`'s are done in a way, where the preprocessor just takes the file that you are `#include`'ing and copy-pastes in the spot of `#include` statement, when n.h is being processed, it includes q.h, and then class `Q` appears before class `N`. Hence, it doesn't know what the class `N` is, since the compiler works in linear fashion (from the start of the file to the end).

So, it is my suggestion, to remove `#include "q.h"` statement from n.h, since the class N doesn't use class `Q`.